# How do I fix the warning "Unknown attribute android:duration"?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm getting this in Studio 3.3.1:

[image: Unknown attribute]

How do I fix it? I have other projects that are OK but I can't see what difference between them might be causing it. Searches have been fruitless so far.

My project specs are:

compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: It means the autocomplete cannot find the attribute. If it works, it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: is this xml file located in "res/anim" folder?

Comment: Haven't actually got to the point where I can test it yet. Thought I'd better ask now so I'd get a response by the time I did. Yes, it's located in the "res/anim" folder.